# Shiny: Why updateSliderInput works only one time?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write Shiny App that would [update slider input](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/updateSliderInput.html) maximum value dynamically once I am executing arbitrary code when pressing the button:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30),
            actionButton(inputId ="refresh", label = 'boom')
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    counter <- reactiveValues(c = nrow(faithful))

    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
        
        faithful <- faithful[-1:-10, ]
        counter$c <- nrow(faithful)
        updateSliderInput(session, "bins", min = 1, max = counter$c, value = counter/2)
    })
    
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Unfortunately, slider input update works only once! Documentation example suggests to use *observe()* construct watching some reactive values however I would expect that such functionality should also be working when using *observeEvent()* What could be wrong here?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is not the `updateSliderInput`, it is that `counter` is not a reactive so it is not persitent inside the app. Just convert it to a reactive like in this example and it works fine.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      actionButton(inputId ="refresh", label = 'boom')
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  counter <- reactiveValues(c = 10)
  
  observeEvent(input$refresh, {
    counter$c <- counter$c + 10
    updateSliderInput(session, "bins", min = 1, max = counter$c, value = counter$c/2)
  })
  
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I can now see how to use `reactiveValues()` construction. I am still struggling with that `reactive` concept: how could I execute more code? What if my value `c` is result of some arbitrary code?

Comment: Just added one more code example, yet I am not able to understand how to access memory areas of shiny. Once data object is inside 'global' environment arbitrary code works inside `observeEvent` construction

Comment: To see how to use reactive I suggest you see some Shiny tutorials about reactives. Defining a global variable works in this situation, but it is not good practice here. Reactive are supposed to be used in this kind of situation. Have a look at `reactive` `reactiveVal` `reactiveValues` `eventReactive` functions.